# niceEdit editor is only loading the content once through ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting the values of questions through database and i want to edit and update the values of questions.Question heading has to be open in newEdit or fckeditor. As all the values are coming from database but nicEdit is only loading the values of the questions heading which is clicked for the first time, if after that a question is clicked for editing then it does not load the value of that particular question, it shows the value of previously loaded question. I Need your advice to load the data for each question.

add_appraisal.jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor-small/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

            //Get the HTTP Object
            function getHTTPObjectForBrowser(){
                    if (window.ActiveXObject)
                        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
                    else {
                        alert("Browser does not support AJAX...........");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            function showQuestionList(e){
                httpObject = getHTTPObjectForBrowser();
                if (httpObject != null) {
                    httpObject.open("GET", "getAdminQuestion.action?sectionId="+e, true);
                httpObject.send(null);
                httpObject.onreadystatechange = showQuestionListResponse;
                }
            }
            function showQuestionListResponse(){
                if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
                    var res = httpObject.responseText;

                    jsonObj = JSON.parse(res);

                     var n = jsonObj.length;

                       $('#dyntable tr:not(:first)').remove();

                       for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                           var row = '<tr>';
                           var col = '';
                           col += '<td>'+(i+1)+ '</td>';
                           col += '<td>'+jsonObj[i].questionTitle+ '</td>';
                          /*  col += '<td>'+jsonObj[i].questionContent+ '</td>'; */
                           col += '<td><a href="#myModal" onclick="editQuestion('+jsonObj[i].questionId+')" data-toggle="modal" class="editbutton">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;<a class="btn confirmbutton_department" href="deleteQuestionAdmin.action?questionId='+jsonObj[i].questionId+'"> <small>Delete</small> </a></td>';
                           row = row + col + '</tr>';
                           $('#dyntable').append(row);
                      }

                }
            }

            function editQuestion(e){

                httpObject = getHTTPObjectForBrowser();
                if (httpObject != null) {
                    httpObject.open("GET", "editQuestionAdmin.action?questionId="+e, true);
                httpObject.send(null);
                httpObject.onreadystatechange = showQuestionEditResponse;
                }
            }
            function showQuestionEditResponse(){
                if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
                    var res = httpObject.responseText;
                    jsonObj = JSON.parse(res);
                    document.getElementById("editQuestionContent").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("editQuestionTitle").value=jsonObj.questionTitle;
                    document.getElementById("editQuestionContent").value=jsonObj.questionContent;
                    document.getElementById("QuestionEditId").value=jsonObj.questionId;
                    new nicEditor().panelInstance('editQuestionContent');
                    /* new nicEditor({value : jsonObj.questionContent}).panelInstance('editQuestionContent'); */
                }
            }
    </script>


    <form method="post" action="updateQuestionAdmin.action">
                   <div style="width:100%;">
                             <table class="section_table">
                                  <tr>
                                   <td>
                                    <div style="float:left; margin-top:3px;"><label>Question</label></div><div style="float:left;width: 90%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <input type="text" id="editQuestionTitle" name="questionTitle" class="input-large" value="1" style="width:90%;"></div>
                                   </td>
                                  </tr>
                                  <tr>
                                   <td>
                                    <label>Question Heading</label>

                                            <textarea id="editQuestionContent" style="width:650px; height:200px" name="questionContent"></textarea>
                                   </td>
                                  </tr>
                                 </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                   <input type="hidden" id="QuestionEditId" name="questionId" />
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>

                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>

      </div>
      </form>
```